# Finding the (unit) direction vector given azimuth and elevation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spherical-coordinates

I want to calculate a unit direction vector of a direction with given the azimuth and elevation (cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth), respectively
$$\alpha \in [0^{\circ},360^{\circ}), \qquad \beta \in (-90^{\circ},90^{\circ}).$$
I have a right-handed coordinate system with z-up and looking down +y (yes, I have a graphics background :D). I got the hint that it's easy to calculate using trigonometry, but I don't really understand the solution:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\sin(\alpha) \cos(\beta)\\ \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)\\ \sin(\beta)\end{pmatrix}
$$

Can someone explain the motivation behind this solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that the unit direction vector in the $yz$-plane with elevation $\beta$ (and azimuth $0$) is
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \cos \beta \\ \sin \beta\end{pmatrix}.$$
To produce from this the the unit direction vector with azimuth $\alpha$, we rotate *clockwise* about the z-axis, which we can regard as left multiplication by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos \alpha & \sin \alpha & 0 \\ -\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$ so the desired vector is
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos \alpha & \sin \alpha & 0 \\ -\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \cos \beta \\ \sin \beta\end{pmatrix} = \color{#df0000}{\begin{pmatrix}\sin \alpha \cos \beta \\ \cos \alpha \cos \beta \\ \sin \beta\end{pmatrix}}.$$

Comment: I could use some additional explaination on what's going on with that clockwise rotation matrix...

Comment: You might find this article helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix Note that the article generally uses anticlockwise rotations, and so we need to translate the results appropriately. For this it's enough to recall that a clockwise rotation by $\alpha$ is the same as an anticlockwise rotation by $-\alpha$, and that $\sin (-\alpha) = -\sin \alpha$ and $\cos (-\alpha) = \cos \alpha$.