# Calculate direction vector of azimuth and Elevation in NED

Tags: coordinate-systems

I need to calculate the unit direction vector of given azimuth and elevation angles. My target coordinate System is a NED (North east down). 
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll-Nick-Gier-Winkel#/media/File:RPY_angles_of_airplanes.png

I found [Finding the (unit) direction vector given azimuth and elevation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150232/finding-the-unit-direction-vector-given-azimuth-and-elevation) but it is for another coordinate System and i can't reproduce it, because i do not understand this sentence in this post: "I have a right-handed coordinate system with z-up and looking down +y "

Can someone tell me how to get the vector for my coordinate System?

Comment: So due north is $0$ azimuth and due east is $90$ degrees azimuth, is that right? Does a positive elevation angle produce a vector pointing upward from the $x,y$ plane (negative $z$ coordinate) or downward (positive $z$ coordinate)?

Comment: The reason I asked is that I've rarely dealt with NED in the past, and the figure does not actually label anything "elevation" (nor show which direction of pitch is positive--a two-headed arrow points in both directions). But positive elevation $\to$ negative $z$ component is what I would have guessed (that is, the usual convention for elevation would be followed no matter which way the $z$ axis pointed).

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually not convinced the linked question is answered correctly,
but in any case I think it's simpler to answer this question from
first principles rather than try to adapt another question's answer.

---

To summarize NED coordinates, the first coordinate axis points due north (N),
the second points due east (E), and the third points straight down (D).
I will label these axes $x$, $y$, and $z$, respectively,
as shown in your figure.

Start with a unit vector pointing due north, which is in the direction
of the $x$-axis:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
For elevation by an angle $\theta$
(oriented so that positive elevation produces a negative $z$ component),
we rotate this vector to the position
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta \\ 0 \\ -\sin\theta \end{pmatrix}.
$$
For azimuth angle $\psi$, we rotate the vector around the $z$
axis through the angle $\psi$ in the direction of rotation
from the $x$ axis toward the $y$ axis.
Viewing the vector componentwise, the $z$ component is unchanged
but the $x$ component is rotated in the $x,y$ plane so that the
vector becomes
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta \cos\psi \\
                \cos\theta \sin\psi \\
                -\sin\theta         \end{pmatrix}.
$$